# python polymorphism overloading glitch

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to use the overloading function as described in the pep-3124*, I am having some trouble:

```
[luca@artix tmp]$ more foo.py 
from overloading import overload
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(ob):
    """Flatten an object to its component iterables"""
    yield ob

@overload
def flatten(ob: Iterable):
    for o in ob:
        for ob in flatten(o):
            yield ob

@overload
def flatten(ob: basestring):
    yield ob
[luca@artix tmp]$ python3 foo.py 
/tmp/foo.py:2: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
  from collections import Iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 63, in overload
    return register(__registry[fname], func)
KeyError: '__main__.flatten'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    def flatten(ob: Iterable):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 65, in overload
    __registry[fname] = overloaded(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 151, in overloaded
    return register(dispatcher, func)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 199, in register
    signature = get_signature(fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 441, in get_signature
    types = tuple(normalize_type(type_hints.get(param, AnyType)) for param in parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 441, in <genexpr>
    types = tuple(normalize_type(type_hints.get(param, AnyType)) for param in parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/overloading.py", line 468, in normalize_type
    if not typing or not isinstance(type_, typing.TypingMeta) or type_ is AnyType:
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'TypingMeta'
[luca@artix tmp]$
```

Note that I uninstalled the typing module.

---

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3124/

Comment: There is no ``overloading`` in the official Python docs.

Comment: `overloading` is not a standard library module, it's something you've installed by hand.

Comment: I tried searching for this issue without much success.

Comment: "Note that I uninstalled the typing module." Why? How?

Comment: You should probably not be using the third party `overloading` package, but `@overload` from `typing`: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.overload

Comment: The PEP linked is *not* the official Python docs. It has been "Deferred" since "2007", in other words it is *not* part of any official Python release and has not been considered for this for more than a decade.

Comment: @AKX ``typing.overload`` is for static type hinting only. It has no runtime effect. ``functools.singledispatch`` is the closest in the standard library.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oh, you're correct, I was thinking of that one. Figured I'd seen it in the stdlib somewhere :)

Comment: PEP 3124 is *deferred*, and is not part of Python today. The overloading package is outdated, as it hasn’t been updated in 5 yesrs and will not work with your current Python release. Do **not** damage your Python installation by deleting or altering the `typing` module!

Comment: Thanks.  So, is there polymorphism in python???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From to this thread on [GitHub](https://github.com/bintoro/overloading.py/issues/8):

> The downgrade of the typing module helped me (from the python repository) to version 3.5.2.2. You can also forcefully ignore the typing module in the overloading module by assigning `typing = None` after the 30th line in the file `overloading.py`, but I think the typing module features will not be available.

---

UPDATE: As pointed out by [Martijn Pieters ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) and [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) in the comments, it would be much more practical to uninstall the overloading package, rather then degrading your python version, as the standard library already includes `functools.singledispatch()` to cover this functionality.

Comment: I don't care about the typing module

Comment: @LucaSansS The `typing` module cares about you, since it's part of the standard library in the version of Python you're running.

Comment: @LucaSansS Yes, but another module that you might be using might have the `typing` module somewhere in their code.

Comment: Much better idea: **uninstall the overloading package**. You don’t need it, as the standard library already includes `functools.singledispatch()` to cover this functionality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! Can I please include your comment into this answer?

Comment: Sure, but note that MisterMiyagi pointed out the connection to `functools.singledispatch()` before I did.